# Sending a message on a user join event - discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been programming a bot that welcomes a user when they join but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = member.channel
    await channel.send(f'{member} has arrived')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified *where* the channel is that you want to send the message to, and `discord.Member` doesn't have an attribute called `channel`.

You'll have to get the channel via its ID, like so:

```py
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = bot.get_channel(112233445566778899) # replace id with the welcome channel's id
    await channel.send(f"{member} has arrived!")
```

If you want to, you can also get it via its name:

```py
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.text_channels, name="welcome")
    await channel.send(f"{member} has arrived!")
```

---

**References:**

- [`on_member_join()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_join)
- [`Client.get_channel()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel)
- [`Guild.text_channels`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.text_channels)
- [`Member.guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.guild)
- [`utils.get()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get)

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    for channel in member.guild.channels:
        if str(channel) == "member-log":
            await channel.send(f"""Welcome {member.mention}!""")
```

This might help too. Here, we are checking if the channel name is `member-log` and then sending a welcome message to that channel.