# Discord py module Trying to have bot greet users in the server in a specific channel

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm using the discord py module right now which is working fine but I want my bot to greet users in the server like mee6 does

Comment: Welcome to the SO. Please take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and look [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending a message on a user join event - discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62075822/sending-a-message-on-a-user-join-event-discord-py)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the on_member_join event as so.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    await channel.send("Welcome to {} {}!".format(member.guild.name, member.display_name))
```